# Cusps and corners of smoothly parametrized curves

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Consider a smooth injective map $\psi:\mathbb R \to\mathbb R^2$ with only one critical point (or singularity) at $t=0$, i.e. $\psi'(0)=(0,0)$ and $\psi'(t)\neq (0,0)$ for $t\neq 0$. A simple example is the *cusp* $\psi_c(t)=(t^2,t^3)$. The critical point is of finite order: $\psi''(0)\neq (0,0)$ (the order is thus $2$).

In some sense the *corner* $E= \lbrace (x,0): x\ge 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace (0,y):y\ge 0 \rbrace$ should be simpler than the cusp. However, the only way I see a parametrization is with critical points of *infinite* order, e.g. $$\psi_E(t)=\begin{cases} (e^{1/t},0), & t <0 \\ (0,0), & t=0\\(0,e^{-1/t}) ,&t \ge 0\end{cases}.$$

Is there a smooth parametrization of $E$ having only one critical point of finite order?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be quite simple: Say, $\psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ is a parametrization with $\psi(0)=(0,0)$ and there are $t_1<0<t_2$ such that $\psi(t_j)$ is on the $j$th axis. The intermediate value theorem implies that then $\psi(t)$ is on the first axis for all $t<0$ which implies that $\psi_2$ is $0$ for all negative $t$ so that all derivatives of $\psi_2$ vanish at $0$. The same argument implies that all derivatives of $\psi_1$ vanish at $0$.